# Hiding responsive navigation after link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

The issue I am having is when I toggle my responsive menu down, I want it to be when the links are clicked that the menu goes away. Any suggestions or help? Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cheyneosy_/5MCxL/7/)

**Here is the HTML Markup**

```
<header>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <button id="mobile-menu" class="menu-btn">
      <i>=</i>
    </button>
  </div>

  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MY WORK</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**Here is the JQuery :**

```
var menu = $('.navigation ul'), plink = $('#mobile-menu'), go;

function mobileMenu() {
    var ww = $(window).width();

    if (ww>769 && go) { //hide this menu on desktop
        if (menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }

        plink.unbind();
        go=false;
    }

    else if (ww<768 && !go) { //reveal this menu on small screen
        plink.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        go=true;
    }
}

mobileMenu();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add click event handler for the menu li items (use some class for easier manipulation) and in the handler toggle your menu again.

```
$('.navigation > ul > li').on('click', function(){
    menu.toggle();
});
```

You can attach the event for small screens and unbind it for large (as your other logic)

Actually if your menu links refer to another page and in this page you have the same menu collapsed by default you haven't problem.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MCxL/11/)

EDIT: [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5MCxL/23/) with handling of window resize event according to comments

Comment: What do I do if I do not want my navigation to execute other pages, and just stay a one page website? How do I go about that then? @Viktor

Comment: Doesn't the code sample solve your issue? Updated the answer - added fiddle demo.

Comment: You understand that your code that measure scree width is executed only once right? If you want to support for example desktop browser that resize on some moment you may want to add the logic for smaller screens to it. For this case you can try to use window resize event and make measurement and attach/dettach other events inside the window resize event handler :)

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: I changed your fiddle again. Maybe you will want something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/5MCxL/21/. I will include the link in the answer too.

Comment: The logic behind that does work in a way, but it is a very glitchy and when I do resize from mobile back to desktop, then back down to mobile, it does not respond.

Comment: OK, maybe there will be any problems but you should inspect, debug and fix them for your case ;) One problem was that every time an event is attached. Check the last demo again. Please note that my post answers correctly to your question and everything else is just additional information and advises :)